# can I change a parent's async piped properties?

Tags: angular, binding

To give you some more context:

[image]

Red is the parent and Blue is the child component.

The parent just assigns the Observable in the ngOnit

```
this.user$ = this.userService.getUser(this.userId);
```

it doesn't do anything else with it, it's used in the template this way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as usr; else loading">
```

The child receives the two values that can be changed as @Input properties:

```
  <ew-edit-user
    *ngIf="edit===true"
    [(xBox)]="usr.xBox"
    [discord]="usr.discord">
  </ew-edit-user>
```

In the Submit-Handler, it calls the API to save the changes.

```
this.userService.changeProfile(this.frm.xBox.value, this.frm.discord.value).subscribe(() => { });
```

After saving, I'd like to refresh the parent.

Tried the two-way-bindings as shown above, but it has no effect. So before I re-write the Parent and subscribe to the reading-service in the component, I'm asking here for ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing an example code with your problem would help but if i'm understanding your problem right, you should be able to resolve this with the two-way data binding.

Without seeing the code I can only assume that you forgot to add the EventEmitter to the child class. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d6cesn)'s a small example how it could be implemented.

In the HelloComponent I've wrapped the input into an object instead of passing in two values for convenience and notice how the @Output dislayItemChange has the same name as the @Input but with Change in the end - thats necessery for Angular to pick up the change event in the parent. Read more about it [from the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding)

Comment: You're cool. Adding that event (and firing it) did the trick.